# Artisan serve send assets with response headers embedded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Maybe this is something obvious but I'm having a hard time, I just found out that my local PHP environment is delivering static files with the response headers embedded.

This is Laravel 4.1.26 with PHP 5.5.11 on Fedora 20, already tested `laravel serve` and `php -S localhost:8000 server.php`, both with equal results.

I tried with Firefox, Opera and Chromium, it looks like is displaying the raw binary response:

[image: Opera displaying a css file]

This is causing errors on all my js files.

[image]

For what is worth I tried `curl` and `wget -q -O -` and the responses are ok, no headers displayed. This looks like PHP's built-in server issue, where should I dig first?

**EDIT:**

This is not a PHP thing, it has something to do with Laravel's emulation of mod_rewrite with the file "server.php", if I step on the public folder and launch the server with `php -S` (ignoring `server.php` and `laravel serve`) then is all fine.

**EDIT2:**

Just narrowed the search, `artisan serve` runs ok in Debian 8 Jessie with the same PHP version (5.5.11), something is different in the Fedora environment.

Comment: Is there anything at the beginning of server.php which shouldn't be there? What happens if you compare it to [this one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/08cb97fa6deb932c6ccb86947afb46450cc118a2/server.php)?

Comment: @madebydavid diffed both files, exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change:

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
   return false;
}
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
ob_end_clean ();
   return false;
}
```

it solved it for me

Comment: Interesting, but still this behavior looks like a bug to me, have you tried upgrading to latest version? I no longer use Laravel 4 nor Fedora.

Comment: i had this on 5.2 as well as on 5.3.

Comment: might be a php bug, i'm on windows, php 5.6.17