# Laravel 5.4 blade put illegal characters to css/js/img files

Tags: php, css, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I created this morning a new project and I use a free HTML template.

The problem I face is the javascript/img is not correctly loading (meaning checking with developper console show the files contains illegal strings in those).

To get this error I launched (as usual) my projet using `php artisan serve`.

Note that when I run my Xampp (equivalent of Lampp or Wamp) and I browse my projet every js/css/img load properly and no illegal string are added on top of the files.

Here is a capture of what blade append to my files :

[image]

And this is the same file, but with Xampp running instead of launching `php artisan serve` :

[image]

Does anyone have an idea whats going on ? Note that last week (when I worked with `php artisan serve`) everything seemed to be fine, no public file issue.

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull: [Artisan serve send assets with response headers embedded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274475/artisan-serve-send-assets-with-response-headers-embedded/39081171)

Comment: Amazing ! But I can't figure out why, because I worked on my project for 4 month now. And since last week I was able to work on it normally using `php artisan serve`. Do you know if Laravel dev team updated something recently ?